# having difficulty with using session in java for login module

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee

**hi.. stackoverflow team member.**

I am trying to use the HttpSession in java to set some values like userid, so I can use the variable till the session remains present.

I am using spring3.0 for the request mapping. My login check code is given below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/GetLoginCheck.action")
    public @ResponseBody
    Map<String, Object> loginCheck(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        List<Employee> emplist = null;
        try {

            GlobalController.session = request.getSession();
            if (!GlobalController.session.isNew()) {
                this.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
                this.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

                emplist = loginservice.getEmployee(this.getUsername(),this.getPassword());

                if(emplist.size()>0)
                {
                    for(Employee employee: emplist)
                    {
                        this.setEmployeeid(employee.getId());

                        synchronized (GlobalController.session) {
                              GlobalController.session.setAttribute("userid", employee.getId());
                            }
                    }

                }else
                {
                    return getModelMapError("The username or password you entered is incorrect.");
                }



            }else{
                System.out.println("already session created");
                System.out.println("SESSION ID ::"+GlobalController.session.getId());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        logingview = this.loginView(this.getUsername(),this.getPassword());
        return getMapUser(emplist,logingview);
    }
```

and my GlobalController class code is given below

```
public class GlobalController implements HttpSessionListener{


    private static int totalActiveSessions = 0;
    public static HttpSession session = null;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        synchronized (this) {
            totalActiveSessions++;
        }
        System.out.println("Session Created: " + event.getSession().getId());
        System.out.println("Total Sessions: " + totalActiveSessions);

    }
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        synchronized (this) {
            totalActiveSessions--;
        }
        System.out.println("Session Destroyed: " + event.getSession().getId());
        System.out.println("Total Sessions: " + totalActiveSessions);
    }


}
```

**As the user Login my "/login/GetLoginCheck.action" executes and with this I am setting the attribute empoyeeId: 2 to the session.**

**But I open the same url in another pc in lan and login with another user named having empoyeeId: 1.**

The problem I am having is that when I see the log or open the gridpanel having the employeeId:1 it shows me the data belonging to the employeeId:2.

**Also the sessionId get override with the newly logged user session.**

Please suggest me some way I can try to implement session in a proper way, so I get the data and session belonging to the intended employee only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for your replies. I am able to solve my problem with making session as class variable. 
below is the **code I tried to make the session working in my application in the loginCheck method.**

```
HttpSession session;
session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("employeeid", this.getEmployeeid());
```

**and to retrieve the session attribute done with below code**

```
session = request.getSession();
System.out.println("EMPLOYEE ID ::"+session.getAttribute("employeeid"));
```

Answer (score 1):

- Static varables related to class, and have one value per class, not per instance. That's why you have

> Also the sessionId get override with the newly logged user session.

- Every servlet is singleton, so you can get problems when two users will simultaneusly try to login.

Comment: thanks for your response. I understand that I had declared the session as static variable so it has only single instance. Do you have any example I can practice to my application running ?

Comment: javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html and examples http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/Session.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring3.0, why don't you make use of [spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) for the same purpose?

Also if you find spring security too complex, you can always go with [Apache shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)

Comment: thanks for your quick response but I had already implemented the above code correctly also everything is working fine. But only the problem is with the sessionId. I always get changed to the last logged in user sessionId. Please suggest me some working solution I can try it and get my application working.